# Get rid of the "Compare With" and "Replace With" options in Eclipse Plugin context menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

The customer of the project I am working on wants certain options of the context menu gone, namely the "Team", "Compare With" and "Replace With" options. These are provided by other plugins.

So, I went into the ViewPart class and started modifying the code to remove these options. I managed to get rid of the "Team" one by doing as follows:

- In the createPartControl method, I create the context menu and ask for a fillContextMenu method to be called just before rendering the menu:

```
// Context (right click) menu
MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager();
menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
    public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
        MyView.this.fillContextMenu(menuMgr);
    }
});
Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(this.viewer.getControl());
this.viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
```

- In the fillContextMenu method, I filter the unwanted option by iterating the menu contributions and setting the undesired options visibility to false:

```
private void fillContextMenu(MenuManager manager)
{
    String POPUP_LOCATION = "popup:my.view";
    IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);
    menuService.populateContributionManager(manager, POPUP_LOCATION);
    IContributionItem[] items = manager.getItems();
    for (IContributionItem item : items) {
        if (item.getId() != null && item.getId().contains("team")) {
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, I have access to the context menu manager just before it gets rendrered. From there, I can hide or show everything I want... but not the "Compare With" and "Replace With" options. They do not appear in the list of menu contributions. If I try to set all the menu contributions to `setVisible(false)`, they all disappear, but these two stay.

I don't understand where they are coming from. How can they be in the menu and not appear in the menu manager ? Are they default options that are always there ?

Comment: Note that Eclipse code is signed and is not just going to let you install hacked versions of core plug-ins. You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress menu items without modifiying anything. Other menu items can be contributed by any plug-in using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.